# Remove hash from hash of hashes if value is duplicated

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have got such hash of hashes

```
params = {collection_permissions_attributes: {'0' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                                                   '2' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                                                   '3' => {:collection_id => '4'}}}
```

How can I remove completely from `collection_permissions_attributes` item which hash contains duplicated value? So from hash above I would like to have:

```
params = { collection_permissions_attributes: {'0' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                                                   '3' => {:collection_id => '4'}}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) Show the minimally relevant part to your question. Only the internal hash is relevant to your question. The whole `params` is not relevant. 2) What determines that the key `'2'`  and not `'0'` should be deleted? Question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enought! I will edit my question asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way, but it requires Ruby 1.9+, as it depends on the order of the hash's elements.

**Code**

```
newams = {collection: ams[:collection].sort.reverse.to_h.invert.invert}
  #=> {:collection=>{"3"=>{:collection_id=>"4"}, "0"=>{:collection_id=>"1"}}}
```

If for some reason it is desired that the hash elements be in key order, that can be achieved by adding a few more operations, as explained at the end of the "explanation" section.

**Explanation**

```
ams = {collection: {'0' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                    '2' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                    '3' => {:collection_id => '4'}}}
```

First, reorder the hash elements in descending key order, so that when two or more elements have the same value, only the element having the smallest key value will be kept.  To do this and then reconstitute the hash, three steps are required:

```
a = ams[:collection].sort
  #=> [["0", {:collection_id=>"1"}], ["2", {:collection_id=>"1"}],
  #    ["3", {:collection_id=>"4"}]] 
b = a.reverse
  #=> [["3", {:collection_id=>"4"}], ["2", {:collection_id=>"1"}],
  #    ["0", {:collection_id=>"1"}]] 
c = b.to_h
  #=> {"3"=>{:collection_id=>"4"}, "2"=>{:collection_id=>"1"},
  #    "0"=>{:collection_id=>"1"}}
```

Next, we invert the hash, making the keys values and the values keys.  Because hashes cannot have duplicate keys, this eliminates the duplicates:

```
d = c.invert
  #=> {{:collection_id=>"4"}=>"3", {:collection_id=>"1"}=>"0"}
```

Lastly, `invert` back:

```
e = d.invert
  #=> {"3"=>{:collection_id=>"4"}, "0"=>{:collection_id=>"1"}}
```

The hash elements can reordered in key order (should that be desired) like this:

```
e.to_a.reverse.to_h
  #=> {"0"=>{:collection_id=>"1"}, "3"=>{:collection_id=>"4"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of as below :

```
params = {    :employee =>
              {collection_permissions_attributes: {'0' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                                                   '2' => {:collection_id => '1'},
                                                   '3' => {:collection_id => '4'}}}
        }

hash = Hash[params[:employee][:collection_permissions_attributes].group_by do |k,v|
  v[:collection_id]
end.map { |_,v| v.first }]

params[:employee][:collection_permissions_attributes] = hash
```

*output*

```
{:employee => 
    {:collection_permissions_attributes => {
                                             "0"=>{:collection_id=>"1"}, 
                                             "3"=>{:collection_id=>"4"}
                                           }
    }
}
```