# Sorting a hash based on an array representing order

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
data =  {"Blood Group"=>"A", "Next Review Date"=>"22/06/2016", "Tourniquet Time"=>"23", "BMI"=>"21"}
```

I have a sorting order in an array:

```
sorting_order = [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

I want to rearrange the hash according to the sorting order array so that the hash becomes:

```
data = {"Next Review Date"=>"22/06/2016", "Blood Group"=>"A",  "Tourniquet Time"=>"23", "BMI"=>"21"}
```

I tried:

```
sorted_hash = sorting_order.map{|x| data[x]}
```

It returns:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Enumerator: [1, 0, 2, 3]:index>
```

I'm not sure of how to proceed here. What's the way to do it?

Comment: Hashes are "ordered" by order of insertion as of Ruby 1.9 (or something like that). But ordering a hash is a bit of an anti-pattern, IMO; why specifically do you think you need to rely on the order of a hash?

Comment: @DaveNewton Probably to show them in a view or something in an order. My guess is that.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Mine too. My point was that instead of relying on hash order the OP should use a naturally-sequenced structure.

Comment: Hash corresponds to the data entered by the user and their sequence is maintained separately in a different array. Everytime the sequence is changed, I wish to just show the fields according to the current sorting order instead of writing the sequence to the database and making queries. So if its an pattern can you point me to the right direction here

Comment: Hm, I agree! @DaveNewton

Comment: If you have things in the right order in an array then why don't you leave the hash alone and iterate over the array instead?

Comment: Array just contains the order number not the actual data. Thats the reason why I need to sort the hash based whatever the order the array holds at any given time

Comment: @RoboCode IMO you're missing the point. Return an intrinsically-sequenced structure instead of relying on language implementation details. Don't sort the hash. Move the key/value pairs to an array.

Comment: In my experience (albeit as a Ruby hobbiest), a hash's key order can be exploited in many situations. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557456/remove-hash-from-hash-of-hashes-if-value-is-duplicated) is an example. More generally, those who wanted key ordering in v1.9 won the day, so their arguments must have been persuasive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.to_a.values_at(*sorting_order).to_h
  #=> {"Next Review Date"=>"22/06/2016", "Blood Group"=>"A",
  #    "Tourniquet Time"=>"23", "BMI"=>"21"}
```

Comment: This method though a little cryptic to understand first compared to the answer below, is much faster than sorting_order.map{|x| data.to_a[x]}.to_h. I did a benchmark test and time of execution is always less here.

Comment: @RoboCode The sorting speed is a negligible concern compared to most everything else.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
sorting_order.map{|x| data.to_a[x]}.to_h  # We're converting hash to array in each loop, you could define a local var and use it here instead.

 => {"Next Review Date"=>"22/06/2016", "Blood Group"=>"A", "Tourniquet Time"=>"23", "BMI"=>"21"}
```

PS. I was one of the upvoters of @DaveNewton's comment and agree that hashes should not be sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting the hash every time, is it possible for you to store the hash keys in the array which holds the sort order?

like this:

```
 data =  {"Blood Group"=>"A", "Next Review Date"=>"22/06/2016", "Tourniquet Time"=>"23", "BMI"=>"21"}
 sorting_order = ["Next Review Date", "Blood Group", "Tourniquet Time", "BMI"]
```

And when the user changes the order, you simply update the keys in the `sorting_order` array.
Afterwards, when rendering the data, you simply call

```
sorting_order.each { |data_key| render(data[data_key]) }
```