# Sort hash based on conditions

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a hash like this:

```
roles = {
   "teachers"   => [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}], 
   "electrician"=> [{name: "D"}, {name: "E"}, {name: "F"}],
   "painters"   => [{name: "G"}, {name: "H"}, {name: "I"}],
   "carpenters" => [{name: "J"}, {name: "K"}, {name: "L"}],
   "gardeners"  => [{name: "P"}, {name: "Q"}, {name: "R"}], 
}
```

I also have an array `negative_roles` that consists of negative roles:

```
negative_roles = ["electrician", "teachers", "carpenters"]
```

`roles` should be sorted so that all negative roles come later like this:

```
roles = { 
   "painters"   => [{name: "G"}, {name: "H"}, {name: "I"}],
   "gardeners"  => [{name: "P"}, {name: "Q"}, {name: "R"}], 
   "electrician"=> [{name: "M"}, {name: "N"}, {name: "O"}],
   "teachers"   => [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}],
   "carpenters" => [{name: "J"}, {name: "K"}, {name: "L"}], 
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: That sounds like an interesting problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i was trying this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998809/sorting-a-hash-based-on-array-of-order-in-ruby but not much luck with it

Comment: While the latest versions of Ruby have hashes that have a fixed order, traditionally hashes did not have a fixed order. So some will say that ordering hashes is a bad practice. Can you explain why you want them ordered? There may be a way of doing what you want without depending on an ordered hash.

Comment: Also (far more importantly) you have duplicate hash keys. that is not a valid hash.

Comment: Ok i have updated the hash and removed the dups.

Comment: Also to answer your question in a simple way, i'm reading a report file which is in CSV format through which i'm preparing a hash like i mentioned in the question and i'm trying to do aggregation of a particular attribute's value but the aggregations should not be disturbed by some rows which i dont want to consider(business logic). Now the problem is the order of hash is not always same so i want to sort the negative ones in the last such that they will not disturb in the aggregation process.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How can I do it?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to reorder the keys of the hash `roles`. In #1 `roles` is mutated. In #2 and #3, it is not. In those latter two cases, if `roles` is to be modified (as the question indicates), simply insert `roles =` at the beginning. Similarly, in #1, if `roles` is not to be mutated, operate on a copy of `roles` (`roles_cpy = roles.dup`).

As well as `roles`, we are given

```
negative_roles = ["electrician", "teachers", "carpenters"]
```

All three methods below return

```
  { "painters"=>[{:name=>"G"}, {:name=>"H"}, {:name=>"I"}],
    "gardeners"=>[{:name=>"P"}, {:name=>"Q"}, {:name=>"R"}],
    "teachers"=>[{:name=>"A"}, {:name=>"B"}, {:name=>"C"}],
    "electrician"=>[{:name=>"D"}, {:name=>"E"}, {:name=>"F"}],
    "carpenters"=>[{:name=>"J"}, {:name=>"K"}, {:name=>"L"}]}
```

**#1 Use [Hash#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete)**

```
negative_roles.each { |k| roles[k] = roles.delete(k) }
roles
```

**#2 Use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject), [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)**

```
roles.reject { |k,_| negative_roles.include?(k) }.
  merge(roles.select { |k,_| negative_roles.include?(k) })
```

**#3 Use [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)**

```
roles.partition { |k,_| !negative_roles.include?(k) }.flatten(1).to_h
```

I try to avoid converting a hash to an array, modifying the array and then converting it back to a hash. It just seems a bit brutish.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your bad roles:

```
negative_roles = ["electrician", "teachers", "carpenters"]
```

And your "good" roles:

```
positive_roles = roles.keys - negative_roles
```

You can iterate through the hash in that order:

```
(positive_roles + negative_roles).each do |key|
  role = roles[key]

  # ..
end
```

As Beartech mentioned in the comments above, sorting a hash may not always do what you want it to do in Ruby, but you could convert the above to an array of tuples:

```
role_tuples = (positive_roles + negative_roles).map! { |key| [key, roles[key]] }
```

This looks like:

```
[
  ["painters", [{:name=>"G"}, {:name=>"H"}, {:name=>"I"}]],
  ["gardeners", [{:name=>"P"}, {:name=>"Q"}, {:name=>"R"}]],
  ["electrician", [{:name=>"D"}, {:name=>"E"}, {:name=>"F"}]],
  ["teachers", [{:name=>"A"}, {:name=>"B"}, {:name=>"C"}]],
  ["carpenters", [{:name=>"J"}, {:name=>"K"}, {:name=>"L"}]]
]
```

You could then convert it back to a hash (with `.to_h`) if you feel comfortable relying on hashes maintaining their order in Ruby.